# I am getting NullPointerException inside Consumer

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying a Producer/Consumer Problem, but I don't know why I am getting   `java.lang.NullPointerException` inside the Consumer.

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class Producer extends CommonClass implements Runnable {

    private int producerNum;

    Producer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue) {
        queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {

        char ch;

        for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
            queue.add(ch);
            System.out.println("Producer" + producerNum + "produced :" + ch);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is my Consumer class

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class Consumer extends CommonClass implements Runnable {

    private int consumerNum;

    Consumer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue )
    {
        queue = queue;  
    }

    public void run() {
        char c;

        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            c = queue.poll();
            System.out.println("Consumer" + consumerNum + "consumed:" + c);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }

    }
}

package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class CommonClass {

     PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Character>();

}

package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class SyncTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



         PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Character>();

        Producer p1 = new Producer(queue);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        t1.start();

        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(queue);
        Thread ct1 = new Thread(c1);
        ct1.start();

    }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:18)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When you post a question about _any_ exception, please provide in the post the first couple of lines from the exception and indicate _specifically_ where in your code the exception line refers to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the immediate problem:

```
Consumer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue )
{
    queue = queue;  
}
```

That's a no-op statement, assigning the parameter's value back to itself. You want:

```
Consumer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue )
{
    this.queue = queue;  
}
```

Once you've fixed that, you'll *then* have a potential problem due to calling `poll()` (decalred in `Queue`), which will return `null` if the queue is empty. That null reference will then be unboxed to assign the value to the `c` variable (of type `char`).

Use `take()` (declared in `BlockingQueue`) instead, which will block. You may want to specify a timeout, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet its working now , i have one more question  question  if i use PriorityBlockingQueue as a source to Threads  , do i still need to use wait and notify methods in Consumer and Producer respectively ??

Comment: @PreethiJain: It's not clear what you mean by "as a source to threads" - but the general point of blocking APIs is that you *don't* have to use any other synchronization; just use `offer` and `take`.

Comment: I mean as this is a Producer and Consumer  Thread , should we use wait and notify methods in COnsumer and Producer respectively ??

Comment: @PreethiJain: As I said before - no, `offer` and `take` handle the synchronization and coordination for you.

Answer (score 3):

`Use take instead of poll` poll may returns null.

[JavaDoc#poll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#poll%28%29)

> the head of this queue, or null if this queue is empty

Use `put` to add and take to `get` which are blocking methods.