# NullPointerException inside of threaded consumer

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am getting NullPointerException inside Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512949/i-am-getting-nullpointerexception-inside-consumer)

Is this considered to be a bug in Producer , Consumer Scenario ??

**This is my Producer class .**

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class Producer extends CommonClass implements Runnable {
    private SyncronizedStack stack;
    private int producerNum;

    Producer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {

        char ch;

        for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'f'; ch++) {
            queue.add(ch);
            System.out.println("Producer" + producerNum + "produced :" + ch);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**This is my Consumer class**

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class Consumer extends CommonClass implements Runnable {

    private int consumerNum;

    Consumer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            try {
                c = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Consumer" + consumerNum + "consumed:" + c);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**This is my CommonClass**

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class CommonClass {

    PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue = null;

}
```

**This is my Client program**

```
package com ;

import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class SyncTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CommonClass cs = new CommonClass();

        PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Character>();

        Producer p1 = new Producer(queue);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        t1.start();

        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(queue);
        Thread ct1 = new Thread(c1);

        ct1.start();

    }
}
```

**When i run this i get output as**

```
Producer0produced :a
Consumer0consumed:a

Producer0produced :b
Consumer0consumed:b

Producer0produced :c
Consumer0consumed:c

Producer0produced :d
Consumer0consumed:d

Producer0produced :e
Producer0produced :f
Consumer0consumed:e
Consumer0consumed:f
```

This is in case of e and f alphabets .

Is there any problem with this output ??  as i see the statement Producer0produced two time simultaneously and then followed by Consumer0consumed statement simultaneosuly for the letters e and f .

**I fear that with this code will i miss any information produced by Producer ??**

Please advice ??

Thanks in advice .

Comment: Same code , but the  question is different , some people say don't ask multiple questions , in single thread and now you are saying this .

Comment: Don't forget that multiple threads are designed to perform tasks at the same time in any order.  Seeing this behaviour is a good thing. If you only ever saw it alternating like it does at the start it says you don't really need multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any problem with this output ?

Nope. Your producer thread just managed to produce a second item before the consumer managed to consume the first one. That's entirely natural, particularly when you're sleeping for random periods.

Of course you may want to give an upper bound to your queue - and then use [`offer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29) instead of `add` to detect the situation where the queue was full - but the output you've shown is fine.

Answer (score 0):

> as i see the statement Producer0produced two time simultaneously and then followed by Consumer0consumed statement simultaneosuly for the letters e and f .

No, that is to be expected.  You are demonstrating typical asynchronous behavior of multiple threads.  The producer was able to produce 2 letters while the consumer was sleeping.

This is going to happen especially considering that both the producer and the consumer are doing random sleeps:

```
Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));
```

But even without the sleeps, such asymmetric behavior is expected with threaded programs.

Comment: Anyone want to explain the -1?

Comment: Wasn't me, but maybe because this  behaviour is described as a 'race condition' - a phrase normally used to describe incorrect behaviour because of syncro errors.  This code works correctly, (if poorly because of the Sleep() call in the consumer).

Comment: Huh.  To me, race condition doesn't mean bug.  It just is about asynchronous behavior.  His program is a perfect definition of a race between the producer and consumer.  Thanks @Martin.

Comment: Your link says 'A race condition or race hazard is a type of flaw'.  I may be wrong - maybe you were downvoted for some other reason.  Did you foul anyone in last weekends' five-a-side 'Developers vs. Managers' soccer game? <g>

Comment: No soccer game <g> but good point concerning the link.  I'll tweak my answer @Martin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this a bug?**

Answer - **NO** It happens because you are adding Unnecessary sleep.

```
Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 300));
```

I have simplified your version of Producer consumer which is below.

```
public class Example {

public static class Producer implements Runnable {
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue;

    Producer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        char ch;
        for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'f'; ch++) {
            queue.put(ch);
        }
    }
}

public static class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue;

    Consumer(PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumer take :" + queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();// Propagate interrupt
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    PriorityBlockingQueue<Character> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Character>(7);
    executorService.execute(new Producer(queue));
    executorService.execute(new Consumer(queue));
    executorService.shutdown();
}

}
```

Comment: AmitD , Thank you very much for the code , for the current program i agree Thread.sleep is not required , but i will be using the same code , in a  heave traffic web based Application , where the Producer Thread will make Continuous request to server for data , so  i will use Thread.sleep so that the browser will settle down in real time scenario

Comment: Why not use `SynchronousQueue` then your put will block unless there is consumer.